# jQuery Accordion not respecting settings

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to use jQuery's `accordion` effect in a Rails 3.2 application. It's a simple screen in which the user can choose to pay by either credit card or PayPal. The accordion feature itself does indeed work. However, I can't get it to respect any of the settings I initialize it with in CoffeeScript:

```
$('#paymentdiv').accordion ->
  icons: false
  heightStyle: 'content'
  animate: 300
```

The icons still show up, the height is not large enough to contain the content, and it doesn't matter what you set the animation to, it's always the same.

```
  <div id="paymentdiv">
    <h3><%= image_tag "/img/promo/credit card title.png" %></h3>
    <div id="creditcarddiv">
      <%= simple_form_for @subscription, url: wizard_path, method: :put, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }, defaults: { label_html: { style: "width:200px;" } } do |f| %>
        <% unless @subscription.errors.blank? %>
          <div class="error_messages">
            <%= f.error_notification message: "We're sorry, but it appears that the information provided is incorrect or incomplete.", style: "color:#b94a48;" %>
            <p>Please verify that the information provided is correct and try again.</p>
          </div>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.input :payment_card_token, as: :hidden %>
        <%= render 'credit_card_fields' %>

        <div id="stripe_error" style="position:relative; padding-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px;">
          &nbsp;
          <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit "Subscribe", type: :image, src: "/img/promo/Subscribe Button.png", id: "ebay_subscribe_button" %>
        <%= link_to "Skip", next_wizard_path %>
        <%= image_tag "/img/promo/Secure Server icon.png", id: "secure_server_image" %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
    <h3><%= image_tag "/img/promo/PayPal.png" %></h3>
    <div id="paypaldiv">
      <p>PayPal Here!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So I'm keeping everything in the following format for Accordion:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Header1</h3>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
  <h3>Header1</h3>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

My hypothesis thus far is that I'm either doing the Coffeescript wrong, or I'm missing some kind of supporting JS or CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY Coffeescript was wrong. I should have been passing in a function, so I shouldn't have used the `->` operator. Passing in a hash works perfectly:

```
$('#paymentdiv').accordion
  collapsible: true
  active: false
  icons: false
  heightStyle: 'content'
  animate: 300
```